repeating-conic-gradient treated as simple conic-gradient on chrome print preview?
I have been trying to create a background effect for a certificate design using repeating conic gradient to create blue and transparent rays, using this background value: repeating-conic-gradient(from 0deg at 50% 50%,rgba(0, 203, 254, 1) 0% 1%,transparent 1% 2%), but chrome print preview just treats this as simple conic gradient. is there a way around it or just not possible?
it displays the rays fine on the html preview on the web browser, but doesnt work on the chrome print preview.
Small Edit: Also i tried using the print color adjust property and setting this repeating conic gradient as important in the print media rule, which are some of the related solutions, but it still doesn't work. Although, it is visible as simple conic gradient in the preview.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Is this only in print preview or in printed document too?

@Justinas yes, it is the same in the printed document as well

This looks like a problem in Edge/Chrome (Windows11) as Firefox shows the rays OK [both tests had the background image printing option set in the print dialog - Edge/Chrome just shows a solid block of cyan, FF shows the rays].

@AHaworth yes, i concluded this to be a browser issue as well, not sure why this is the fallback, had to use an svg as an alternative to this, which works ok.

May be worth reporting it.

done. Thanks for the help.

Properly implementing repeating conic/sweep gradients in Chrome's PDF generator was a TODO. Fixing this was tracked as Chromium 374253366 and fixed with [pdf] Implement sweep gradient tilemodes in Chrome 132.0.6828.0 and later.
Unfortunately, the only workaround before this Chromium change is to use a conic-gradient and manually write out the repeats.
